# How to update marker on every time when I got new LatLng?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, real-time

I am getting Updated LATLNG in every 5 sec and I want to update marker on updated Latlng here is my code :

```
 private class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        lat = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("lat"));
        longD = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("long"));
        userLat = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("userLat"));
        userLong = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("userLong"));
        latDest = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("latDest"));
        longDest = Double.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("longDest"));
        userDropLocation = intent.getStringExtra("userDropLocation");
        userManualLocation = intent.getStringExtra("userLocation");
        driverLatLng = new LatLng(lat, longD);
        userLatlong = new LatLng(userLat, userLong);
        dropLatlong = new LatLng(latDest, longDest);
        Log.d("@@Latdriver", String.valueOf(lat));
        Log.d("@@longDriver", String.valueOf(longD));
        Log.d("@@latLngCurrent", String.valueOf(latLngCurrent));
        Log.d("@@driverLatLng", String.valueOf(driverLatLng));
        Log.d("@@userLat", String.valueOf(userLat));
        Log.d("@@userLong", String.valueOf(userLong));
        Log.d("@@userManualLocation", userManualLocation);
        Log.d("@@userDropLocation", userDropLocation);

        String urlToDrop = getDirectionsUrl(driverLatLng, dropLatlong);
        DownloadTask downloadTask1 = new DownloadTask();
        downloadTask1.execute(urlToDrop);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_green))
                .position(new LatLng(latDest,longDest )));

        MarkerOptions a = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(driverLatLng);
        Marker m = map.addMarker(a);
        m.setPosition(driverLatLng);
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        builder.include(driverLatLng);

        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 150);

        map.animateCamera(cu);


    }
}
```

In the above code It is adding every time new marker on updated along how to resolve this please help me, Thank you in advance I would appreciate every answer here

Comment: as i check each time you are creating the new marker when your get the new latlng you can create global marker and set its postion where you got the new latlng .

Answer (score 1):

Every 5 secs is too frequent. it will drain user's battery like anything. 30-60 seconds should be fine.

problem is here

```
MarkerOptions a = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(driverLatLng);
        Marker m = map.addMarker(a);
        m.setPosition(driverLatLng);
```

you are creating new Marker every time .

Use field variable for a marker . initialize it for the first time. and from next time onwards just set the position of a marker to new lat lng.

your code should be something like this

```
private Marker driverMarker ;

// inside broad cast receiver     

if(null==driverMarke){
    MarkerOptions a = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(driverLatLng);
        driverMarker = map.addMarker(a);

}

driverMarker.setPosition(driverLatLng);
```

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: Marker.setPosition(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)' on a null object reference

Comment: change it if(null!=driverMarke) to  if(null==driverMarke)